# Result Complement

Tags: grammar

一个人去很危险，带上这个吧。

Yīgè rén qù hěn wéixiǎn, dài shàng zhège ba.

It's dangerous to go alone — take this.

Is this translation correct?
I don't understand the usage of a result complement in this situation.

Would the sentence make sense if one were to omit 上 ?
By extension, is 上 necessary?

Comment: see this user's comment on use of "上" as complement of direction or result in What is the difference between 穿 and 穿上? https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/14124/what-is-the-difference-between-%e7%a9%bf-and-%e7%a9%bf%e4%b8%8a  (excerpt from "实用现代汉语语法")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Result complement** https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Result_complement
>
> *There are endless examples of these 'attempt' or 'procedure' verbs in Chinese which don't include an outcome. The majority of Chinese verbs are like this, in fact. Some examples:*
>
> *看 means 'to look' but doesn't include the result 'to see'.*
>
> *听 means 'to listen' but doesn't include 'to hear'.*
>
> *写 is similar to the English verb 'to write', in that it doesn't specify what the result of writing was (e.g. whether it was correct or not).*
>
> *记 describes an attempt to remember, without specifying if the information was forgotten or successfully remembered.*
>
> *杀 means something like 'to try and kill', whatever the result is.*
>
> *All of these verbs need a result complement to describe a complete action with its result.*

For the same reason:

- 带 means 'to carry/ to bring' but doesn't include which direction. Like the examples above. the verb 带 (carry/ bring) needs a result complement to describe a complete action with its result.

For example:

带回 = bring back

带走 = carry away

上 in 带上 implies 附上/ 加上 (along with / additionally)

- 带**上** = carry/ bring **along**

> 一个人去很危险，带这个吧。
>
> (because)it is dangerous to go alone, (therefore) carry this.
>
> 一个人去很危险，带[**上**]这个吧。
>
> (because)it is dangerous to go alone, (therefore) carry this [**along**]

A clearer Example:

> 这条路线很危险, 不带**上**几个保镖不行 (this route is dangerous, You must bring a few bodyguards **along** with you)
>
> if you just wrote '带几个保镖' 带 could mean 'guide', 'lead', or 'carry'

- 带着 means 'carrying'

> 一个人去很危险，带[**着**]这个吧 (because)it is dangerous to go alone, (therefore) **carrying** this (with you).

Comment: All these grammar rules have started to make something basic slip my mind..could you give me an example using 带回　or 带走　because I am not sure how the sentence structure works..I am pretty sure the object goes in between dai and the result complement..but I am not sure..it has been a long day.  THANKS AGAIN for the explanation.  :)

Comment: 1. 他从中国[带回了]大量的现金 - He [brought back] huge amount of cash from China. 2. 他从中国[带走了]大量的现金 - He [carried away] huge amount of cash from China. 3. 他[带了]大量的现金[回]中国. 4. 他[带了]大量的现金[去]中国.

Comment: 1. 这条路线很危险，你得带几个保镖。- [Since you already stated a reason '这条路线很危险' - 带(上)  bring (along) is implied in these sentences, if '带' means 'lead' or 'guide', it  would make no sense]　2. 这条路线很危险，你必须带几个保镖。[bring (along) is also implied here]　3. 这条路线很危险，你有必要有保‌​镖陪伴你 [ 'you must have a few bodyguards accompany  you' ]  and [ 'you must bring along a few bodyguards with you' ] express the similar sentiment.  Just phrased differently

Comment: Could I also say...这条路线很危险，你得带几个保镖。　OR　　这条路线很危险，你有必要有保镖陪伴你。 ?? OR 这条路线很危险，你必须(需要）带几个保镖。  In the last sentence, I am not sure which is better..because I have the impression that 需要 is more of a _personal need_ and also can be used before a **noun** (which is irrelevant in this case as it is before a **verb**..) but, it also means something _definitely required_.  That said, 必须 usually is a **modal verb** or **auxillary verb**, but　须 also refers to something _mandatory_ due to **logic** or **culture**..which I feel both could be applicable in this case (depending on context, i.e. SIlk Road) 对不对？

Comment: Okay..you pretty much answered my question..but I didn't phrase it properly because my edits did not work.  I appreciate again your help..sorry to rephrase, but, for the sake of clarity of everyone I think it is good on this site..maybe it also changed from my original question..sry it did not post earlier :(  THANK YOU AGAIN..so is both 1 and 3 and 2 and 4 correct?  Do you have a preference of using either in your first comment?  With the result complement structure?  They both mean exactly the same thing??

Comment: Oh...I think I get it now, they mean different things..thx again :)

Comment: Also, I FORGOT to add Shang into those sentences..moreso I was curious about the usage of dei, bixu, biyao, xuyao etc as opposed to bu dai and bu xing?